# Dynamic section header height on runtime

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have `UITableView` in view controller with a section header and in the header, I have one `UITextView` with scroll disabled and pinned all `UITextView` edges to its super view.[image]

Here is the code for automatic height change

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CreatePostHeaderView") as? CreatePostHeaderView else {
        return nil
    }
    
    return view
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

And also set the estimated Height with this code

```
 tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 75
```

But on runtime when the text of `UITextView` exceeds height of 75, it doesn't change after that regardless of UITextView content. So, Do I need to add anything to make sure the table section header height changed according to `UITextView` content? Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this will work because I do that for my tableHeaderView and never tried for a section header: `view.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(size, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.defaultLow, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.fittingSizeLevel))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When performing some action that changes the height of a cell (including header / footer cells), you have to inform the table view that the height has changed.

This is commonly done with either:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

or:

```
tableView.performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)
```

In this case, you want to call this when the text in your text view changes - easily done with a "callback" closure.

Here is an example of using a `UITextView` in a reusable `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

This will apply to loading a complex view from a XIB, but since this view is simple (only contains a `UITextView`), we'll do it all from code. This example uses 3 sections, each with 12 rows (default table view cells).

First, the table view controller class - no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections, so just create a new `UITableViewController` and set its custom class to `MyTestSectionHeaderTableViewController`:

```
class MyTestSectionHeaderTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var myHeaderData: [String] = [
        "Section 0",
        "Section 1",
        "Section 2",
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.rowHeight = 50
        
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
        
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 75
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "defCell")
        tableView.register(MySectionHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: MySectionHeaderView.reuseIdentifier)
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return myHeaderData.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defCell", for: indexPath)
        c.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return c
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        
        let v = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: MySectionHeaderView.reuseIdentifier) as! MySectionHeaderView
        
        v.myTextView.text = myHeaderData[section]
        
        v.textChangedCallback = { txt in
            self.myHeaderData[section] = txt
            tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
        }
        
        return v

    }
    
}
```

and this is the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` class. Note that it needs to conform to `UITextViewDelegate` so we can tell the controller the text has changed (so it can update the height when needed), and we pass back the newly edited text to update our data source:

```
class MySectionHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView, UITextViewDelegate {
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = String(describing: self)
    
    var myTextView: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.isScrollEnabled = false
        return v
    }()
    
    var textChangedCallback: ((String) -> ())?
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        contentView.addSubview(myTextView)
        
        myTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            myTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            myTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            myTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        myTextView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        guard let str = textView.text else {
            return
        }
        textChangedCallback?(str)
    }
    
}
```

The result:

[image]